# Cutting fields of DF command using grep and cut

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Having trouble with this command. I'm trying to run df, cut columns 1 and 5 and also get rid of the headers. So far, I have this:

```
df | cut -f 1,8 -d ' ' | grep -v Filesystem
```

However, it only prints the first value in the "Use%" column.

Answer (score 1):

With gnu df

```
df --output=source,pcent | tail -n +2
```

Answer (score 0):

Better do :

```
df -hP | awk 'NR!=1 && /Filesystem/{print $1, $5}'
```